# Android update textview timer and refresh map content?

Tags: android, google-maps, timer

I have the following layout file. Basically I have google map and at the top left I have a `TextView` where I will need to keep counter say every 15 seconds to refresh the map. The layout is fine.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context="com.example.ns.appversion1.MapActivityFragment1"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/textRefresh"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:text="Refreshing 1"
                android:textColor="#03A9FA"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Below is my codes. In the view function I try to implement a `Handler` function to keep the counter. Thus every 15 seconds I want to call the `JSON` function to retrieve the latest lat long values and plot on the map accordingly. I am now stucked at the first step here where it gives me error saying cant access variable `timeleft`,`m_handlerTask` and `m_handler` from within inner class? I want to show the count down so the user will know in next 15 seconds counter the map will be refresh?

```
public class MapActivityFragment1 extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback  {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    TextView tv;
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MapActivityFragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MapActivityFragment1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MapActivityFragment1 fragment = new MapActivityFragment1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_activity_fragment1, null, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textRefresh);
        Handler m_handler;
        Runnable m_handlerTask ;
        final int timeleft=15000;
        final m_handler = new Handler();
        final m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(timeleft>=0)
                {
                    // do stuff
                    Log.i("timeleft",""+timeleft);
                    timeleft--;
                    tv.setText("Refreshing in "+timeleft);

                }
                else
                {
                    m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask); // cancel run
                }
                m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);
            }
        };
        m_handlerTask.run();

        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }


    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

I have tried Charu's solution as below.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_activity_fragment1, null, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textRefresh);
        MyCount counter = new MyCount(15000, 1000);
        counter.start();

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: you were saying a lot. what exactly you want to do ;) 1.refresh map in 15 s , or use a count down ?

Comment: I just want to show a count down on my label

Comment: Say it count from 15 then 14 then 13 etc till 1 then i call a json to refresh the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will demo a  countdown from 15 to 0 (-1 at a second), and this task will repeat again after every 15 seconds!

```
    public class YourActivity extends Activity {


    TextView textView;
    android.os.Handler customHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);


        customHandler = new android.os.Handler();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
    }


    // count down timer is an abstract class, so extend it and fill in methods
    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textView.setText("done!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textView.setText("Left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {

            // 10000 is the starting number (in milliseconds)
            // 1000 is the number to count down each time (in milliseconds)
            MyCount counter = new MyCount(15000, 1000);
            counter.start();
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 15000); // repeat body after  15 seconds
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135515/discussion-on-answer-by-charu-android-update-textview-timer-and-refresh-map-con).

Answer (score 0):

Just an advice.

As far as I know handler runs on main thread, so, try to use light processing tasks, once this thread is responsible for all UI interactions. If you need to process large amount of data or need some time, like waiting for server's response, I suggest you to use another thread for it, like using an Async task or coroutines.

Personally, I like to use both. I use the handler to create this event and once is time to do it, i call a function that runs in another thread to do it.